# In-browser gzip decompression using HTML5 Blob API and createObjectURL?

Tags: javascript, html, blob, gzip, compression

I am investigating an idea to make use of the browsers built in gzip decompression facility by using the [HTML5 Blob API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). With a trick the browser may do the uncompressing when the Blob is referenced as an Object URL via [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) and then inserted into the DOM. It appears that the only obstacle is the ability to set Content-Encoding for the blob.

If it would be possible to set the content-encoding of the Blob Object to gzip the browser will decompress the Blob and it will be possible to return the result to a library or application. If this would be possible, it may result in a stable and fast decompressing solution that costs just a few bytes instead of for example 22.6kb for pako_inflate.min.js.

I hereby want to inform if anyone knows of a solution to use a javascript Blob to uncompress gzip data in the browser.

The code that I use to test via the browser console is the following. It will change the background of a page to green on success.

```
    /* create blob */
    var createBlobUrl = function(fileData,mimeType) {
        var blob;

        // Create blob
        try {
            blob = new Blob([fileData], {type: mimeType});
        } catch (e) { // Backwards-compatibility
            window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
            blob = new BlobBuilder();
            blob.append(fileData);
            blob = blob.getBlob(mimeType);
        }
        return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    };

    /* CSS: body, * { background:green; } */
    var zip = window.atob('H4sIAAAAAAAA/0vKT6nUUdBSqFZISkzOTi/KL81LsUovSk3Ns1aoBQCLj6wTHQAAAA==');

    function str2bytes (str) {
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(str.length);
        for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
            bytes[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
    var bloburl = createBlobUrl(str2bytes(zip),'text/css');
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');
    link.setAttribute('type','text/css');
    link.setAttribute('href',bloburl);
    document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I don't think you can do this. There's disabled [ArchiveReader implementation in Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=772434), which could allow to read entries from a ZIP file, but it's not on the standards track. Maybe bring it up as a FileAPI feedback? Another idea I had is to use a service worker to create a response with appropriate headers.